# The resistance of angular momentum

Tags: angular-momentum

A ring (M=1,r =1)) is mounted on pivots (P) so that it can spin on the z axix (on its center) and on the x-axis. (p-p').
[image]

If it spins on the z axis at v = $\omega$ (=10), its KE will be (50) = **K**, I am not using units because a superficial reader might mistake this as a homework question.

If it spins on the p-p' axis with same KE its $\omega$ = speed will be $v\sqrt{2}$, is that right?

Now, suppose we give the ring an impulse at B and start it spinning when the ring is already spinning on the z-axis, what will happen? Its L will oppose a change of the plane of rotation, the ring cannot precess because of the pivots, and the speed of the ring on the x- axis will have to win the whole resistance of the magnitude of the angular momentum.

Can you quantify how the speed of the ring on the x-axis will vary with time/radians? Also, how will the speed of the ring on the z-axis be affected by the second spin?

Comment: *I am not using units because a superficial reader might mistake this as a homework question.* Astute readers are not fooled so easily! And they might resent the insult if they disagree with your implication that this is *not* a "homework and exercises" question.

Comment: You need to specify more details. If the body is supported by two 1-DOF pin joints, you need to specify the order at which they are connected.

Comment: If **B** is into the plane then the disk will spin by _P_-_P'_ axis. I don't see what the confusion is.

Comment: @sammygerbil, ..."*if the cap fits...*"

Comment: @ja72, please explain what is the *confusion* to which you are referring. As to the pin joints, I don't know  what is the *order* you ask, just thing of an ordinary gyro on 2 gymbals instead of the usual 3. The gyro can spin on 2  normal planes instead of 3, so it can't precess when the gyro's rotation plane is shifted. Is it more clear now?